# Why won't this small change to my YouTube API call work?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

In the YouTube API docs I found [this example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial#Submitting_Partial_Feed_Request):

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&max-results=10&fields=entry[yt:statistics/@viewCount>1000000]
```

Which, of course, works fine.

Now, let's say I wanted to find all the videos that matched surfing, and had more than 1 like (should be quite a lot) - I tried changing it to this:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&max-results=10&fields=entry[yt:rating/@numLikes>1]
```

But it [returns nothing](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&max-results=10&fields=entry%5Byt%3arating/@numLikes%3E1%5D).

The docs on `yt:rating` are [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3arating), and I appear to specifying the correct fields. So why am I not getting any results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding v2 to the URL:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=surfing&max-results=10&fields=entry[yt:rating/@numLikes>10]
```

The ratings don't appear in the first version of the API